# UIAlertController - Order of actions

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I wanna show alert window by pressing on button. Usual thing. But I'm confused that I try to show button "Awesome" at first, but always "Cancel" button stay the first. How can I fix it?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello world", message: "Testing", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome", style: .default){(_) in print("Awesome")}
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(cancel)

alert.actions.forEach( { (action) in print( action.title! ) } )

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[Irregular order of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO6ec.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of these statements:  alert.addAction(action)
alert.addAction(cancel), and if it doesnt  work then  I guess its the default behaviour of UIAlertController to put cancel action on left

Comment: yeah, I tried this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the order will not work as default position of cancel button is left.

Change the action style for cancel button type to UIAlertActionStyleDefault instead of UIAlertActionStyleCancel.

Comment: Thx, it works. But still I don't understand the difference between .default and .cancel style of buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it will work for you.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let destructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
}
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

}
alertController.addAction(destructiveAction)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: "Cancel" is not a destructive action. That's a poor name for the variable. Not to mention that variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: okay i changed it see my answer @rmaddy